# Reduce the amount of information returned from standard service actions

Tags: 7, services

I have a Drupal 7 Services that my frontend call when I want to get (for example) all comments of node XYZ. All works, but I want to reduce informations that this call return (yes, from the backend). For example "hostname, mail, changed, registered_name, signature" are all data that I don't want to return back. Other example: if I call "user/X" service path it return "password, mail" and other informations that I consider private.

So, how can I intercept and remove this data before that service module send it back to the caller?

Comment: I believe the user retrieve resource only returns the password hash if the user requesting the data has the 'administer users' permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For user objects specifically there's [`hook_services_account_object_alter()`](http://api.devtrac.org/api/services/docs!services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_account_object_alter/7.x-3.x), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_services_account_object_alter($account) {
  unset($account->mail);
}
```

For other entity/resource types there's [`hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()`](http://api.devtrac.org/api/services/docs!services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_request_postprocess_alter/7.x-3.x), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  // Manipulate $result till your heart's content.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To know which is the service that the external user has called I check "callback" entry of $result.  Is there another more correct way ? $controller does not give me usefull informations.